# How to resize image using phpThumb class

Tags: php, phpthumb

I'm try to re size image using [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) class(this open source php class)

so i call above class

```
$phpThumb = new phpThumb();
$phpThumb->setParameter('w', 900);
$phpThumb->setParameter('h', 86);
```

but image not re size correct dimensions help to solution for this problem

Comment: Have you checked the manual?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, [PHPThumbnailFactory](http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/) is a really good class which you can use instead of the one you are currently using. With it, you could just say:

```
$thumb->resize(100, 100)->save('/path/to/new_thumb.jpg');
```

or something like:

```
$thumb->adaptiveResize(175, 175);
```

There are a lot of options. Check out [the github](https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/wiki/Basic-Usage)

Comment: ^Definitely a recommended class. Have been using it for a while now.

Comment: Nice Class but `is more up to date` i don't agree .. the only update in 3 years was https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/pull/39 which was a patch if you check http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/docs/phpthumb.changelog.txt you should see that it has been worked on several times in less than 2 years

Comment: I agree I didn't look that good ;) sorry will update my post.

Answer (score 0):

After you set the parameters you want like output destination, etc. you need to call the GenerateThumbnail function and then one of the output functions:

```
if ($phpThumb->GenerateThumbnail()) {
    $phpThumb->OutputThumbnail();
}
```

Comment: yes i did but i want how to give correct way  pass height and width in tho the  phpThumb class

Comment: $phpThumb->setParameter('w', 900) is the correct way. So it looks like you're doing that correctly. Have you tried removing your height parameter?